# Non-uniform indentation with enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I am using an `enumerate` environment to enumerate over a set of equations. Everything works fine but, if there is a page break when generating the pdf while the enumerate is not complete, the indentation at the next page appears to be centered rather than the usual left aligned. Can anyone tell me why this happening?

The code is as follows:

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Lot of contents and equation go here.......

\vspace{15cm}

The different equation obtained using KKT conditions are:

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Primal feasibility constraints are:
        \begin{equation} -(Bw^{(1)} + e_2b^{(1)}) + q \geq e_2, q \geq 0 \end{equation}
    \item Complementary Slackness conditions are:
        \begin{equation} \alpha^T(-(Bw^{(1)} + e_2b^{(1)}) + q - e_2) = 0, \beta^Tq = 0 \end{equation}
    \item Multiplier Positivity constraints are:
        \begin{equation} \alpha\geq 0, \beta \geq 0 \end{equation}
    \item Gradient conditions with respect to $w^{(1)}$, $b^{(1)}$ and $q$ are:
        \begin{equation} A^T(Aw^{(1)} + e_1b^{(1)}) + B^T\alpha = 0 \end{equation}
        \begin{equation} e_1^T(Aw^{(1)} + e_1b^{(1)}) + e_2^T\alpha = 0 \end{equation}
        \begin{equation} c_1e_2 - \alpha - \beta = 0 \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

After the second point, a page break occurs and the indentation goes haywire. Any help would be great. One more thing: I haven't imported any package besides `mathtools`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please modify your example to be a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Make it easy for others to help you: please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Will this be good enough?

Comment: I removed the twosided argument and it works fine.....I don't know exactly whats it job is...But works for me if I don't use it....Thanks anyways for responding....

Comment: The posted code isn't an example of the problem described, there is no page break????

Comment: I edited the question so that the example has a page break in the enumerate. The result looks OK to me. Please either describe what you think is wrong with that output or edit the document to show the problem you see.

Comment: @Shaun the twoside option gives different margins on odd and even pages (with wider margins on the outside edges), as in a book If that is all you are seeing that is the expected behaviour and is normal in any document to be printed twosided.